# Double entry accounting - asset account

Tags: accounting, double-entry

- I understand a loan account of a customer is an asset account of the bank.
- A credit to loan account by bank decreases asset account.

According to double entry accounting for every credit there should be an associated debit. Which account is debited by bank, how and why?

Comment: Accounting questions seem to be off-topic here, but think through the lending process. I give you cash (an asset), and I add to my notes receivable (another asset). On the other end you pay me cash and decrease your loan balance. That's a very simple example, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about banks for a second - from your post history it seems you are fixated on that as you expand your understanding of the financial system.

Let's assume you run a coffee shop. You let people pay you $100 in advance, and then future purchases are at a discount. If I give you $100, you haven't "earned" it yet, because you haven't sold me any coffee, so you can't record it as revenue under general accounting principles. So you record it as:

```
Dr Cash $100 [debiting your cash account, because you do actually hold that cash]
    Cr Accounts Payable $100 [because you owe me either my $100 back, or you owe me $100 of coffee when I buy it]
```

Your balance sheet would look like:

*Assets*

Cash $100

*Liabilities*

Accounts Payable $100

The same is true for a bank. **When you deposit money in the bank, they owe it back to you. So their balance sheet would look like**:

*Assets*

Cash on hand $100

*Liabilities*

Deposits payable to customers $100

**And when the bank turns around and loans some of its available reserves to someone needing a car loan**, it would be in reverse, debiting its loan receivable account, and crediting its cash account. After the money comes in and then goes out, it would look like:

*Assets*

Loan receivable from customers $100

*Liabilities*

Cash deposit payable to other customers $100

Comment: To be precise I was more interested in banking system. I got the lending i.e. loan receivable account is the internal tracking mechanism of bank which gets debited and cash account is the user operated account where the loan amount from bank is deposited in the form of credit. Can you tell me the same way which account is credited if his cash account is debited?

Comment: @DeepakKumar Yes, that is the last example I show. Also - you seem to be implying that the bank credits something *visible to the customer* when it debits their cash account. That is not true. As a bank customer, I don't care how they account for the information on their side, it doesn't impact me at all.